# How to make a button which is present in a common view to both Admin and rest of the users, visible only to the Admin using Express and NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am using NodeJS, Express and MongoDB for a project. In my project, there is a view which is common to both Admin and rest of the users. I want to add a button to the view which is visible only to the Admin. Can anyone please help me in implementing this?
Here is the code for the button:

```
<form action="/videos/skills/edit_360_zidane" method="POST">
  <input type="submit" class="button-0" value="Edit Videos">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a templating engine like [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/), you can pass a variable to indicate that the rendering is being done for admin or not:

```
res.render('theTemplate', { admin: true });
```

and in the template file, depending on the nature of the `admin` variable, you can either render the button or not:

```
if admin == true
    button Admin!
```

Note: Jade is now known as [Pug](https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/2184).